# How to make an iPhone view transparent?

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have developed a project that has a single view. Now I want the view to be transparant so that I can see the iPhone menu. Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't see the springboard in your apps.

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT possible to do that. You can't make the whole app transparent so that you see the springboard icons. 
Of course, you could set a homescreen screenshot as background image in your app. But, as already said, it's not possible to do that what you want.